# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (Node.js + MongoDB) while storing query result in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
router.route("/card").post(function(req,res)
{

  var response = {};
  mongoOp.find({$and: [
                  {"Mycardid" : req.body.id},
                  {"Mycardtype" : "professional"}
               ]}.function(err, results){
                      console.log(results);
               })
};
```

I m trying to store query result in `result` variable. It gives me errors near `}]}.function(err, results)`. `mongoOp` is my connection object. Error is `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Any suggestions about why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says it all you are missing a closing brace ) also you have to use a comma before you call the anonymous callback function, on successfully finding your data.

```
 router.route("/card").post(function(req,res)
{

  var response = {};
  mongoOp.find({  $and: 
  [{"Mycardid" : req.body.id},
  {"Mycardtype" : "professional"}]}),function(err, results)
   {
  console.log(results);
 }
)};
```